# adapter.notifyDataSetChange() doesnt update my adapter

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
public class ListasCompra extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<Lista> listaCompras = null;
private ListaAdapter adaptador = null;

private static ListasCompra instancia = null;
private static Context context = null;

private Button aceptar = null;
private Button nueva = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_de_listas);

    listaCompras = LocalService.getDbListas().getListas();

    aceptar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aceptarlistas);
    aceptar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    nueva = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nuevalistas);
    nueva.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(context, NuevaLista.class));
            //finish();
        }
    });

    if(listaCompras!=null){
        adaptador = new ListaAdapter(this, listaCompras);
        setListAdapter(adaptador);
    }else{
        listaCompras = new ArrayList<Lista>();
        adaptador = new ListaAdapter(this, listaCompras);
        setListAdapter(adaptador);
    }

    context = this;
    instancia = this;
}

/**
 * Ciclo Vida de Actividad
 */

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    listaCompras = LocalService.getDbListas().getListas();
    adaptador = new ListaAdapter(context, listaCompras);
    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

What I want, is the adapter to update everytime it gets on the method "onResume", which is everytime the Activity re-appears for the user......

My problem is that it is NOT updating using this method, anybody knows why??

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked with Log if the onResume Method gets really invoked as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont create your adapter every time you resume your activity. Create it once in `onCreate()` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()`.

BUT, your biggest issue, is that you are creating a new Adapter in onResume() and never attaching it to the ListView! If you must keep your code as is, then add `setListAdapter(adaptador)` after you create your new adapter in `onResume()`

Comment: Thanks! I didn´t know it was working this way........Now I am gonna change all my code to do it the way you mean....

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate(...)` you do this...

```
adaptador = new ListaAdapter(this, listaCompras);
setListAdapter(adaptador);
```

In doing that, you are passing a reference to the `ListView` - that reference is to the `ListAdapter` created by the call to `new...`.

In `onResume()` you do this...

```
adaptador = new ListaAdapter(context, listaCompras);
adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

...now `adaptador` has a new reference to a new `ListAdapter` but the `ListView` itself is still maintaining a reference to the first `ListAdapter` that you instantiated in `onCreate(...)`.

The easiest thing is to remove the code from `onCreate(...)` altogether and simply let `onResume()` handle creating the `ListAdapter` and calling `setListAdapter(...)`.

Comment: Creating a nwe adapter every time the app resumes is quite a waste. You only need to create it once

Comment: @Mimminito: OK - I worded that wrong. I always put a check in place in `onResume()` to see if the adapter is `null` or not and create and set the `ListView` to use it if it needs to. My point is that data may change often so it is best to do this sort of thing in `onResume()` and not in `onCreate(...)`.

Comment: Sure, having a check is good practice. I was just making sure people didnt get the impression creating new resources every time the app resumes is good pratice, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Mimminito: No problem - when you posted your comment and I re-read my answer I realised I hadn't worded it in the best way. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: Thanks to all, I understood the diference. I changed everything, and now, I am not creating an instance of the list. Now I am updating the list itself and everything is working properly!